# Как хранить в Store React компоненты?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

То есть у меня есть набор каких-то заранее созданных компонентов на react, и мне необходимо сделать для них общий store, где хранилось бы информация о каждом компоненте(показан или скрыт и тд.) и сам компонент
`

```
[
 {name: 'FirstComponent',
  comp: <First />,
  isOpen: true
 },
 {name: 'SecondComponent',
  comp: <Second />,
  isOpen: false
 }
]
```

`

И уже потом работать с ними в главном компоненте

Answer (score 0):

`redux store` должен хранить сериализуемое состояние.

Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос - хранить компоненты в `store` нельзя.

Поэтому как вариант - хранить уникальные строковые идентификаторы для компонент.

Например:

1) создаете ключ в `store`: `showYourBlock` - которое например будет `bool` значением.

2) далее в вашей `root` компоненте в `render` пишете

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {showYourBlock && <YourComponent />}
             </div> 
         )
    }
```